# How many Outlets can you put on a 14-2

Tags: wiring

Barcode how many outlets can you put on a 14-2 Wire

Answer (score 1):

In the U.S. the NEC has no limit on the number of outlets per circuit for residential, some county's do or have had a limit based on the commercial limits of 180va per yoke or strap. since the question says 14 gauge wire we use 80% max draw or 12 amps. So the counties that impose this limit use 8 as the maximum for 15 amp circuits and 10 as the max for a 20 amp circuit, or this is how the county I live in did it until the last code cycle where they now use the NEC and there is not a limit to residential outlets. There is an example in the code book that shows 10 outlets on a 15 and 13 on a 20 because they were allowed to use 100% but my county used to require the derate because the ampacity of the wire is supposed to be 125% for continuous loads or loads that are running for 3 hours or longer.

Answer (score 1):

For Dwelling Units (Residential Wiring) there is no limitation on number of general purpose outlets. You can put as many on a circuit as you want without violating the NEC. Be careful, there are a lot of rules governing receptacles and you have to really understand them. Check out NEC 220.14, the whole bit, but specifically (J) is for dwelling occupancies. Look at (J1),(J2),(J3) for the different types of receptacles and look up those cross-references listed.

Now, if you are in any other type of occupancy not specifically mentioned in the article (i.e, not dwellings, Banks or Office Buildings), you use 220.14(I) and do a calculation of 180 volt-amps per strap (for example, a common duplex receptacle has two devices but only one yoke or strap, so it is 180 watts or volt-amps). For a store, for example, you do the math: 15a x 120v = 1800va(watts); 1800va divided by 180va = 10 duplex receptacles, or 10 straps with devices. Also note there are other rules for fixed multi-outlet assemblies.

Answer (score -1):

In a residence the code does not dictate the number of receptacles that are allowed on one 14-guage 15-Amp circuit.  It is based upon the number of square feet the circuit/receptacles is planned to cover in the house.  The code allows an unlimited number of receptacles on a limited area of 550-sq feet.  A home that has 1800 square feet of living space is required to have at least four circuits for general purpose lighting, the receptacles are included in this considered lighting load.

Comment: I am not sure where you are getting your values. For residential lighting 1 15amp circuit is required for every 600 sq ft or 1 20 amp circuit for 800 sq ft. Per table 220.12 residential can also be calculated at 3va per sq ft